# ggplot2 - templates with multiple layers based on multiple data.frames

Tags: templates, ggplot2, layer

I would like to build a plot template with two layers, each layer being based on a different data frame.

```
my.df1 <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
my.df2 <- data.frame(ybar=5)
my.df3 <- data.frame(x=11:20, y=11:20)
my.df4 <- data.frame(ybar=15)

layer1 <- ggplot(my.df1) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
layer2 <- geom_hline(data=my.df2, aes(yintercept=ybar), lty=2)

# test 1 OK  - I get my points and a line at y=5
p1 <- layer1 + layer2
p1

# test 2 OK  - first template is fine
p2 <- layer1 %+% my.df3
p2

# test 3 doesn't work - I expected a horizontal line at y=15 with my new points
p3 <- p2 + layer2 %+% my.df4
p3
```

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I found the answer.  I'm not sure if it's the most elegant way to solve it,
but it works.

```
# test 3 - works now!
layer2$data <- my.df4
p3 <- p2 + layer2
p3
```